# how to download files from python azure function with post method

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-python-sdk

**I am creating azure python function which will eventually create kml file with some information and now when i call the function URL with post method it should download me the file **

**I have written simple code but its downloading anything**

```
file_name = "PIG_test.kml"
lambda_path = file_name
f = open(lambda_path,'w')
#here will do some preprocessing which will 
f.write(footer)
f.close()
with open(lambda_path, "rb") as f:
    b = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")
```

**can anyone please answer this ?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level have you gone through this link

Comment: yes but didnt find any relevant solution

Comment: when you make HTTP POST call to your function, what does it return? are you returning the response body that contains your file content? are you returning proper mime type ? show us the code snippet where you do `return func.HttpResponse( body = b, ...`

Comment: refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python) to properly fill the `body`, headers like `Content-Length` and the MIME type of your http `response`.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpResponse` method consist of below **Arguments** which we cannot add any instructions on post method

```
HttpResponse(body=None, *, status_code=None, headers=None, mimetype=None, charset=None)
```

Instead of that, you can use the below steps to achieve this

```
data = func.HttpResponse("Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully." + str( lines) )
with open(file_dwn_name,'w') as f:
f.write(str(data.__body))
f.close()
with open(file_dwn_name) as f:
lines = f.readlines()
return data
```

You can store the response information in `variable` and use it. And you can try to create one file and add that information in file. In this way only you can save and store the response data in azure function.

[image]

We store this information in file

[image]